# Can a lambda function have a bool value of false?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Is it possible, that a lambda function can return a **False** value, when given to the **bool function**?

This lambda function for example yields **True**:

```
bool(lambda x:[])
True
```

Comment: Lambdas are just an alternative way to write functions. You can create a class that behaves as a function and is itself falsey, but it would not be a lambda function.

Comment: So functions are always evaluated as true?

Comment: Functions are truthy by default, like nearly everything. You can create something customised, but it wouldn't be a lambda function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only the objects specified in [Truth Value Testing](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing) in the docs, as well as objects whose `__bool__` or `__len__` methods return `False` or `0` respectively, are falsy objects.

Everything else (yes, this includes any `lambda`) is truthy.

Answer (score 3):

no, you can not do that with pure `lambda` expressions.

```
lambda x:[]
```

is of the type

```
<class 'function'>
```

and as [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing) says, there is nothing of that type that will turn out to be *falsy*  - so it will come out *truthy*; i.e. passing it to `bool` will return `True`.

if you want a funtion (a callable) that evaluates to `False` i would exactly do what is described in [khelwood's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55393649/4954037).

Answer (score 2):

Lambdas are just an alternative way to write functions. Like nearly everything, they are truthy by default. You can create a class whose instances behave as functions and are themselves falsey. They wouldn't be lambda functions, but there's no reason that should be a problem.

For instance:

```
class FalseyFunction:
    def __init__(self, func):
        self.func = func
    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.func(*args, **kwargs)
    def __bool__(self):
        return False

>>> f = FalseyFunction(lambda x:[])
>>> f(0)
[]
>>> bool(f)
False
```