# How to avoid ifs for every command?

Tags: python

I am building a virtual assistant for myself and it feels wrong and ineffective to ask for every command by an individual if like here as example:

```
WAKE = 'hello'


while True:
    print("Mic ready")
    text = voice.get_audio()
    if WAKE in text:
        if "note" in text:
            voice.speak("What do you want to note?")
            print("What do you want to note?")
            text = voice.get_audio()
            Vcm.note(text)
        else if "timer" in text:
            voice.speak("How long is that timer supposed to run?")
            print("How long is that timer supposed to run?")
            text = voice.get_audio()
            Vcm.timer(text)
        else:
            voice.speak("At your service")
            print("At your service")
            text = voice.get_audio()
```

Isn't there an more efficient way to check which command to execute?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! If the code works and you're looking for advice on improving it, [codereview.se] is the appropriate place. But see https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5777/a-guide-to-code-review-for-stack-overflow-users first.

Comment: Use a data-driven approach. Create a dictionary that maps words to search for in the input to functions to call. Then loop over the dictionary and call the corresponding function when it matches.

Comment: Python's way for ```else if``` is ```elif```

Comment: Python 3.10.xx now has a switch/case block: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66877137/421195

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could separate your commands into functions:

```
def note():
    #note body

def timer():
    #timer body

def default():
    #default body
```

Then wrap your commands in a dictionary:

```
commands = {
    'note': lambda: note(),
    'timer': lambda: timer()
}
```

and define default separately:

```
default_command = lambda: default()
```

Then you can check what is in text:

```
for word in text:
   command = commands.get(word, None)
   if command not None:
       command()
       break
else:
    default_command()
```

Not sure this is what you wanted, but it may make your code more sparse if you have many commands.

**EDIT**:

According to [Can a lambda function have a bool value of false?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55393472/can-a-lambda-function-have-a-bool-value-of-false), lambda expressions act 'truthy'. So you could simplify the last bit too!

```
for word in text:
    command = commands.get(word, None)
    if command:
        command()
        break
else:
    default_command()
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll try it out!

Comment: Good idea, however, since text is a string, word doesn't go through every word like "Hello" then "make", but it goes through every letter one by one: "H", "e", "l" etc.
Therefor no command will ever be executed-

Comment: Btw, the code above and the function declaration are in different files

Comment: I fixed the word problem, but then when "command()" gets called it tells me that I miss a parameter for "note()", which i do, but when I change "command()" to "command(text)" it gives me an error of too many arguments

Comment: Split the text on spaces using the .split() method. Find usage under the strings section of the docs: https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str

Comment: I apologize, this one is on me, it took me 10 seconds of a youtube video to find a solution! Still thank you for the Idea

Comment: @Havelex, no worries! If you're happy with solution mark it as the best fit! Glad I could help :)

Answer (score 1):

````
while True:
    print("Mic ready")
    text = voice.get_audio()
    if WAKE in text:
        words = text.split(" ")
        for word in words:
            command = commands.get(word)
            if command:
                command(text)
                break
        else:
            vcm.default()
    ```
````

```
commands = {
'note': lambda text: note(text)
```

}